# Any way to bulk revoke oauth tokens

Tags: oauth2, oauth, refresh-token, accesstoken

So I have an app that is managing several oauth access/refresh tokens and it would be great if I revoke all the tokens I have.

I am aware of the [Salesforce's revoke endpoint](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_revoke_token.htm). But it seems I can only revoke one token at a time. No ideal if I am trying to revoke hundreds of tokens at the same time.

Is there an alternative to hitting the `/services/oauth2/revoke` in a for-loop?

Comment: There's a limit of five tokens per connected app per user (older tokens are automatically revoked). As such, do you really have hundreds of tokens, or just a few?

Comment: These are user access/refresh tokens. So practically speaking, anywhere from 2 to 500.